# How can I fix a stagnant river?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I embarked in a river location, in which the river shared some squares with a murky pool. Apparently there's a bug in the current version of Dwarf Fortress, which means that the river is slowly becoming stagnant, spreading from the intersection tile.

How can I fix this? Is there another program that can be used to edit the location to move/delete the murky pool and remove the stagnant-flag from the affected river tiles?

It's slowly creeping closer to my well, so please hurry!

Comment: I'm not certain of this, but I seem to remember reading somewhere that if the water is multiple z-levels deep, the top z-level will stay clean. That may just be for when the ground is causing the dirtiness, though.

Answer (score 3):

PRIOR to version 0.34.9, you could not fix the problem of stagnant water contaminating(spreading) to other water. Toady changed Dwarf Fortress in version 0.34.9 so that fresh water spreads through stagnant water.

In dealing with stagnant water if you have no fresh water source: the dwarf forturess forums state that you can use a screw pump to purify water. Just make sure the purified water stays isolated from all stagnant water.

Dwarves will drink stagnant water from a well. The only serious downside is that you will need soap to be used with it to clean the wounds of your injured dwarves, otherwise they will get an infection.

Comment: Would putting pure water in contact with stagnant water fix the river?